# How to use Cross_validation output of svm-train?

Tags: classification, svm, accuracy, libsvm

I am getting very poor values with a certain data set I have. I tried to use the -v option of svm-train but later realized that this does not produce any model file for prediction.

So what is the next step after running the train with -v 10.  I get some output like below but do not know how to use this for any next step (of training  or prediction). I have done a fair bit of reading (in SO, the guide.pd on the libsvm site) but still have a long way to go to piece the whole thing together. The ultimate goal is to improve the accuracy of the dataset I have, nothing I have done so have has helped me go beyond a 50% accuracy.

optimization finished, #iter = 267
nu = 0.641509
obj = -67.948758, rho = 0.929905
nSV = 79, nBSV = 58

```
 .
 .
 .
```

optimization finished, #iter = 236
nu = 0.864000
obj = -107.939566, rho = 0.949724
nSV = 121, nBSV = 99
Total nSV = 158
Cross Validation Accuracy = 44.8864%

Comment: This is a bit hard to follow. We can't know why the model doesn't predict better w/o more information about the data, the model, etc. It always could be that there isn't really a relationship. Are you just asking about the code (how it works / how to use it)? (Nb, that would be off topic here.)

Comment: No it was not a coding question but more how to use it. It took me a while to realize that using a -v does not generate a model file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the cross-validation `-v` option to optimize your parameters. Then run the model again using the identified optimal parameters.

In your example, it would appear that the optimal value of the $\nu$ (i.e., nu) parameter was $0.864$. Now that you know this, you can re-run the model again without `-v 10` and instead with `-n 0.864`. The cross-validation accuracy is indeed low, but there's not enough information here to determine why.

Comment: Thanks for a reply. Why does the output above have only nu but say no C or gamma?  On the accuracy I did ask a question on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/q/36374912/2129139) a while earlier but did not get a reply :-) Not sure if that was a wrong forum.